# Setting custom or using system PYTHONPATH in KDevelop

Tags: python, pythonpath, kdevelop

I'm looking for a way to specify a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to KDevelop since it seems to ignore system `PYTHONPATH` (I tried setting it in all standard profile files, including `/etc/profile`).

As a result, running a python script that imports a module that I am actively developing  (i.e. not in `.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`) via the KDevelop "Run" leads to an `ImportError`.
Obviously running the same script from the terminal works fine because the system's `PYTHONPATH` is properly configured.

Is there a way to tell KDevelop about `PYTHONPATH`?
The Python plugin does not seem to be configurable...
And I tried setting `PYTHONPATH` in "Settings > Environment" but that did not work either.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The PYTHONPATH does not seem to set in the AppImage version of KDevelop (tested with version 5.6.1). If you're using the AppImage version in Linux, one way to set the PYTHONPATH is to execute the AppImage like this in the terminal (change the paths as needed):

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/username/custom/path ./KDevelop-5.6.1-x86_64.AppImage
```

To specify more than one path, delimit the paths with a colon :

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/path1:/home/path2 ./KDevelop-5.6.1-x86_64.AppImage
```

I tried the Ubuntu distribution package version of KDevelop, which is a little bit older (v5.5), and the PYTHONPATH got set perfectly via a custom Environment (Settings -> Environment) within KDevelop (without requiring a terminal command), which is why I think the problem seems to only affect the AppImage version of KDevelop.